# Who keeps the record of each international cricket match?

Tags: statistics, records, cricket

There are lot of websites (like [ESPN](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/stats/index.html) or [Yahoo](http://cricket.yahoo.com)) that mention the statistics and records of all the international / domestic cricket matches. But, is there any international reputed agency that keeps track of all the international cricket matches?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The local governing body will determine what status particular games are - First Class, List A, Test, ODI, T20 International and whatever.

As a consequence internationals of whatever form are ratified by the board - or boards - involved. The scorers for a game, normally appointed by the teams ([law 4](http://www.lords.org/laws-and-spirit/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-4-the-scorers,30,AR.html)), will have to submit their (agreed) cards to that governing body.

The national boards will keep their own record, but there's no 'official' body for results and statistics.

The ICC lay down [a lot of rules and guidelines](http://www.icc-cricket.com/rules_and_regulations.php) for many aspects of the games, but I can't find anything mandating that particular feeds should be available to third parties. The ICC haven't yet tried to copyright the scores (as some American sports leagues have tried to).

For example, Wisden is [explicitly (#20)](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/story/243912.html) unofficial!